# Turbo C++ and GCC (using codeblocks on windows) evaluate the same ternary expression differently

Tags: c++, gcc, operator-precedence, turbo-c++

I have this expression

```
(*p % 3 != 0) ? *p = (*p) + 1 : *p = (*p) + 2;
```

In Turbo C++ it evaluates to 14 if *p is 11 and to 35  if *p is 33

In GCC (Windows) it evaluates to 12 and 35 respectively which is what is expected

It works fine when parenthesized to the following format:

```
(*p % 3 != 0) ? (*p = (*p) + 1) : (*p = (*p) + 2);
```

Is there any explanation for this difference? I'm guessing it comes down to differences in the precedence order used by the compilers but cannot pinpoint the root cause

Comment: What happens if you add parentheses everywhere?

Comment: It works fine then, which is what led me to believe a precedence issue

Comment: I think Turbo C++ must be binding `%` tighter than `*`...  OK, maybe not.  The parenthesized version does nothing with `*p%3`

Comment: That doesn't explain why parenthesizing the assignments fixes it.

Comment: Why do you write code like this in the first place? Is this for a obfuscated C contest? If anything, write `*p += (*p % 3) ? 2 : 1;` which is at least _somewhat_ more readable. Though `if` would really be preferrable (I'm not even sure if all these dereferences on both sides of assignments aren't triggering UB...).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ternary conditional operator is different in C and in C++. The expression `a ? b : c = d` is parsed...

- as `(a ? b : c) = d` in C, and
- as `a ? b : (c = d)` in C++.